# ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException in Knapsack Scala

Tags: algorithm, scala, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve Knapsack problem in Scala using dynamic programming .As a part of requirement I also need to show which items are picked to be filled in Knapsack.But I am getting "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException".
And so far what I have code is like :

```
availableMoney is equivalent to weight of knapsack.products.channels is equivalent to value[] in knapsack.products.price is equivalent to weight[] in knapsack.

def knapSack(availableMoney: Int, products: List[Product]) : Int = {
    var wt = List[Int](products.length)
    var value = List[Int](products.length)
    for (product <- products) {
      value ::= product.channels.length
      wt ::= product.price
    }

    val matrix = Array.fill(2, 2)(0)
    val picks = Array.fill(2, 2)(0)


    for (i <- 1 to products.length){
        for (j <- 0 to availableMoney){
            if (wt(i-1)<=j){
                matrix(i)(j) = max(matrix(i-1)(j),value(i-1)+matrix(i-1)(j-wt(i-1)));
                if (value(i-1)+matrix(i-1)(j-wt(i-1))>matrix(i-1)(j))
                    picks(i)(j)= 1;
                else
                    picks(i)(j)= -1;
            }
            else{
                picks(i)(j) = -1;
                matrix(i)(j) = matrix(i-1)(j);
            }
        }
    }

    matrix(products.length)(availableMoney)

}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the exception?

Comment: `for (i <- 1 to products.length)` should probably be `for (i <- 1 to (products.length - 1) )`. I can't remember if the max in a range is exclusive or not.

Comment: The operator `to` is Range.Inclusive, while `until` is Range.Exclusive. If you use an IDE and hover over these operators, you'll see the description (inclusive/exclusive). So it should probably be `until products.length`

Comment: `val matrix = Array.fill(2, 2)(0)` creates a 2x2 array but then you index it by `i` and `j` which seemingly could be arbitarily bigger. How is that going to work?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues I think:

- j runs from 0 to availableMoney, and is then used as an index into `picks` and `matrix` which have been initialised to specific sizes, so if availableMoney exceeds those dimensions, it will fail
- i runs from 1 to products.length but is also used as an index into `picks` and `matrix`, so will miss 0 and if there are more products than the second dimension size, it will fail

Use some println debugging to check more closely what is going on. Looks like an interesting algorithm. Post us a solution once you get it working :)